# Is there a way to connect thunderbird/lightning to the redmine's calendar?

Tags: redmine, icalendar, thunderbird-lightning

I just started my adventure with the Redmine 3.0, the project manager.

I can't Google out if there is an option to export its calendar to e.g. thunderbird-ligthning. There are some [plugins](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/PluginICalendarExport), but they are not compatible with current Redmine 3.0. I couldn't find out anything relevant in the [changelog](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Changelog), too.

Can anyone tell me from their own experience, if (and how) this feature is available?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, anything that exports to the [ics](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545) format can be made available to Thunderbird/Lightning, or any other calendaring program. The other option is to make use of the [caldav](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4791) protocol, which is also standardized.

I have heard reports that [this fork](https://github.com/buschmais/redmics) of the redmime ics export plugin works for 3.x, but I haven't tested it myself. Maybe you can give it a try.

If you would like to create your own, I'd suggest adapting [sabreDAV](http://sabre.io/) to use redmime as a backend. As an example for how to write a custom sabre frontend for a different service, check out [this work](https://ci.open-paas.org/stash/projects/OR/repos/esn-sabre/browse).